# WHERE and WHERE NOT in SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

How would I use a WHERE and WHERE NOT in the same SELECT SQL query?

For example, I could have a table called fruits.

```
ID | Name       | Colour
-------------------------
1  | Strawberry | Red 
2  | Apple      | Red
3  | Grape      | Red
4  | Banana     | Yellow
```

From this table, I could execute a `SELECT * FROM [fruits] WHERE Colour = 'Red'`, and it would retrieve the following:

```
ID | Name       | Colour
-------------------------
1  | Strawberry | Red 
2  | Apple      | Red
3  | Grape      | Red
```

However, I would like to exclude `Apple` from the single request above, I could use a `WHERE NOT`, but this would return all fruits, including `Banana`.

How would I write an SQL query so that it would result in the following, a specific colour being chosen, but excluding a specific fruit:

```
ID | Name       | Colour
-------------------------
1  | Strawberry | Red 
3  | Grape      | Red
```

I am using MsSQL 2014, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you just not use where name <>'Apple'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have multiple clauses in your `where`:

```
select * 
from [fruits] 
where Colour = 'Red'
  and Name <> 'Apple'
```

Comment: Yes, that has appeared to have worked for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can add multiple conditionals to your WHERE clause just by using keywords `AND` and `OR`.

For example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [fruits] 
WHERE Colour = 'Red' AND NOT Name = 'Apple'
```

Comment: Double quotes are for delimited identifiers. Use single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * 
FROM [fruits] 
WHERE 
Colour = 'Red'
and Name <> 'Apple'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from [fruits]
where Colour = 'Red' and Name != 'Apple'
```

Comment: Skip that old, deprecated `!=`, use `<>` instead.

Comment: I prefer to use it because it's available in every `C` based language.

Answer (score -1):

You can write following query

```
SELECT * FROM [fruits] WHERE Colour = 'Red' and Name<>'Apple';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM [fruits] WHERE Colour like 'Red' and Name not like 'Apple';
```